# Angular 4 Lazy Load Module with canLoad or canActivate guard direct url/

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have tried using canActivate and canLoad in two different module levels, and I am still unable to directly access the lazy loaded module.

In app.routing.module.ts

```
   import { AuthGuardImpl } from './lazy-load/auth-guard.service';
import {AuthGuard} from './lazy-load/auth.service';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'lazy', canLoad: [AuthGuardImpl], loadChildren: 'app/lazy-load/lazy-load.module#LazyLoadModule'},
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [AuthGuardImpl, AuthGuardService]
})
```

Where the above code works if you don't navigate to `http://url.com/lazy` directly. But go to `http://url.com/` then follow a router link to the lazy module.

Similarly I tried:

```
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.service';
import { AuthGuardImpl } from './auth-guard.service';


const lazyRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LazyLoadComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardImpl],
    children: [
    { path: 'dashboard',  loadChildren: 'app/lazy-load/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(lazyRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [AuthGuardImpl, AuthGuard]
})
```

Which again, does not work going directly to `http://url.com/lazy`, but will work if the app loads, and then the user navigates to `/lazy` by routerlink.

Is it possible to navigate to a direct url for a lazy loaded module that uses a guard?

Comment: I have narrowed down the issue to an async issue in my service. I will update my answer, once I have it completely solved.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this in my application and it seems to work fine. Are you referring to running at development time? Or after deploying to production?

You can download my sample code here if you want to take a look and compare: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Routing/tree/master/APM-Final

Oh ... I just looked closer at the URL you posted and it looks like you are referring to production. You need to implement URL rewriting on your server in order to handle those "deep links". How you do that depends on the type of server you are using.

Comment: I am referring to running at development time from the CLI, but you bring up a very good point about URL rewriting that will also need to be addressed.

I looked through your sample project, and it does that mine should act like yours. I wonder what I am missing.

Comment: If you run mine does it work like expected? And what version of the CLI are you using?